# fourth order accurate approx

Tags: numerical-methods

> Prove that the following is a fourth order accurate approximation of the second derivative of a function $f$: $$f''(x_0) = \frac{-f(x_0+2h)+16f(x_0+h)-30f(x_0)+16(x_0-h)-f(x_0-2h)}{12h^2} + O(h^4)$$ Find the leading order error term.

**Here are my workings below, 
 1. Are they correct?
 2. How do I find the leading order error term? looking for some help with this**

Using taylor expansion:

$$
f(x_0+h) = 
f(x_0) + h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) 
+ \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(x_0) 
+ O(h^4)
$$

$$
f(x_0-h) = 
f(x_0) - h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) 
- \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(x_0) 
+ O(h^4)
$$

$$
f(x_0+2h) = 
f(x_0) + 2h f'(x_0) + 2 h^2 f''(x_0) 
+ \frac{4 h^3}{3} f'''(x_0) + O(h^4)
$$

$$
f(x_0-2h) = 
f(x_0) - 2h f'(x_0) + 2 h^2 f''(x_0) 
- \frac{4 h^3}{3} f'''(x_0) 
+ O(h^4)
$$

Calculate:
$$
-f(x_0 + 2h) + 16f(x_0 + h) - 30f(x_0) + 16f(x_0 - h) - f(x_0 -2h)
$$

Which is
$$
\begin{aligned}
&
- \left[
f(x_0) + 2h f'(x_0) + 2 h^2 f''(x_0) 
+ \frac{4 h^3}{3} f'''(x_0) 
\right]
\\
&
+16
\left[
f(x_0) + h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) 
+ \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(x_0) 
\right]
\\
&
-30
f(x_0)
\\
&
+16
\left[
f(x_0) - h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) 
- \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(x_0) 
\right]
\\
&
-
\left[
f(x_0) - 2h f'(x_0) + 2 h^2 f''(x_0) 
- \frac{4 h^3}{3} f'''(x_0) 
\right]
\\
&
+ O(h^4)
\end{aligned}
$$

Which evaluates to 
$
12 h^2
$
to give the required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your expression evaluates to $12h^2\color{red}{f''(x_0)+O(h^4)}$, not $12h^2$, which doesn't give you the error estimate $+O(h^4)$ (only $+O(h^2)$) after you divide by the denominator $12h^2$.

To get the explicit $O(h^4)$ term means you need to expand to order (at least) 6.  To save space, I'll note that since the numerator
$$S:=-f(x_0+2h)+16 f(x_0+h)-30 f(x_0)+16 f(x_0-h)-f(x_0-2h)$$
is even in $h$ only the even-order derivatives appear.  Writing $[h^n]F$  for the coefficient of $h^n$ in the Taylor series expansion of a (sufficiently smooth) function $F(h)$, we have
\begin{align}
[h^n](f(x_0+mh))&=[h^n]\left(\sum_{j=0}^n f^{(j)}(x_0)\frac{(mh)^j}{j!}+o(h^n)\right)\\
&=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}m^n
\end{align}
so
$$
\boxed{\color{blue}{[h^n]S=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\bigg[-(2)^n+16(1)^n-30(0)^n+16(-1)^n-(-2)^n\bigg]}}
$$
For even $n>0$,
$$
-(2)^n+16(1)^n-30(0)^n+16(-1)^n-(-2)^n
=-2(2^n-16)
$$
So we can write down the coefficients immediately
\begin{align}
[1]S&=0\\
[h^2]S&=\frac{-2(2^2-16)}{2!}f^{(2)}(x_0)=12f''(x_0)\\
[h^4]S&=0\\
[h^6]S&=\frac{-2(2^6-16)}{6!}f^{(6)}(x_0)=-\frac{2}{15}f^{(6)}(x_0).
\end{align}
Hence
$$
S=12f''(x_0)h^2-\frac{2}{15}h^6f^{(6)}(x_0)+o(h^6),
$$
which rearranges to
$$
f''(x_0)=\frac{S}{12h^2}+\left(\frac{1}{90}f^{(6)}(x_0)+o(1)\right)h^4.
$$
I.e., the leading order error term is $\frac{1}{90}f^{(6)}(x_0)h^4$.

Comment: does this prove the first question? or the error term?

Comment: This proves both.

Comment: so the second term is the error term? should it be small o or big 0? and how did you get that error term?

Comment: could you expand the details the I could accept the solution

Comment: @user123: I've expanded it slightly.  The little $o(1)$ is there to save me from typing "+ higher order terms" (because $S$ need not be a polynomial).  Hopefully all is clear now.

Comment: thanks! I will accept your answer, could you add detail to how you calculated the even derivatives? that is the only thing I am stuck with

Comment: I've reorganised the answer to present the details of the calculation of coefficients in a more coherent manner.

Comment: would my workings be correct if I had expanded it to 6?

Comment: yes, if you expand it to sixth order it would recover what I had written here.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is the Richardson extrapolant of the simple central second order difference quotient
$$
D_2(h)=\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}=f''(x)+\frac{h^2}{12}f^{(4)}(x)+\frac{2h^4}{6!}f^{(6)}(x)+\frac{2h^6}{8!}f^{(8)}(x)+...
$$
Using the Richardson extrapolation formula for second order errors $D_4(h)=\frac{4D_2(h)-D_2(2h)}{3}$ one gets
\begin{align}
D_4(h)&=\frac{4f(x+h)-8f(x)+4f(x-h)}{3h^2}-\frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x)+f(x-2h)}{12h^2}
\\[1em]
&=\frac{-f(x+2h)+16f(x+h)-30f(x)+16f(x-h)-f(x-2h)}{12h^2}
\\[1em]
&=f''(x)-\frac{8h^4}{6!}f^{(6)}(x)-\frac{40h^6}{8!}f^{(8)}(x)-...
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for your submission, is this a complete solution?

Comment: Yes, it show that the divided differences formula has error order $4$ by applying the extrapolation formula to all terms on both sides.

Comment: so then what is the leading order error term?

Comment: The first on the right that still depends on $h$, of the lowest degree.

Comment: could you edit that in to your solution? also this solution is different then the other given, in your opinion is the other wrong?

Comment: It is $\frac{8}{6!}=\frac{1}{3\cdot5\cdot 6}=\frac1{90}$, the final formula is the same as in the other answer, only the approach is a different one, I'm synthetic, constructing the formula from a more simple one, the other analytic, inserting Taylor series into the given formula.

Comment: okay so both answers are the same? but just using different methods to arrive at the same solution?